# Word count with pattern in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So this is the question:

> Write a program to read in multiple lines of text and count the number
>   of words in which the rule i before e, except after c is broken, and
>   number of words which contain either ei or ie and which don't break
>   the rule.
>
> For this question, we only care about the c if it is the character
>   immediately before the ie or the ei. So science counts as breaking the
>   rule, but mischievous doesn't. If a word breaks the rule twice (like
>   obeisancies), then it should still only be counted once.
>
> Example given:
>
> ```
> Line: The science heist succeeded
> Line: challenge accepted
> Line: 
> Number of times the rule helped: 0
> Number of times the rule was broken: 2
> ```

and my code:

```
rule = []
broken = []
line = None
while line != '':
    line = input('Line: ')

    line.replace('cie', 'broken')
    line.replace('cei', 'rule')
    line.replace('ie', 'rule')
    line.replace('ei', 'broken')

    a = line.count('rule')
    b = line.count('broken')

    rule.append(a)
    broken.append(b)

print(sum(a)); print(sum(b))
```

How do I fix my code, to work like the question wants it to?

Comment: Sidenote: there are in fact significantly more words that break this rule than adhere to it.

Comment: Can you please write the right code?

Comment: What if the rule is broken *and* helps both in the same word?

Comment: Probably should be noted that, on top of this algorithm being incredibly inefficient, it would break if the word `broken` or `rule` was part of the input string.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `replace` does not chance stuff in place. What you need is the return value:

```
line = 'hello there'                     # line = 'hello there'
line.replace('there','bob')              # line = 'hello there'
line = line.replace('there','bob')       # line = 'hello bob'
```

Also I would assume you want actual totals so:

```
print('Number of times the rule helped: {0}'.format(sum(rule)))
print('Number of times the rule was broken: {0}'.format(sum(broken)))
```

You are printing `a` and `b`. These are the numbers of times the rule worked and was broken in the last line processed. You want totals.

As a sidenote: Regular expressions are good for things like this. `re.findall` would make this a lot more sturdy and pretty:

```
line = 'foo moo goo loo foobar cheese is great '
foo_matches = len(re.findall('foo', line))   # = 2
```

Comment: That is an expected output

Comment: eh? What is this 'that' of which you speak? you are printing `a` and `b` instead of anything seemingly sensible...

Comment: No no, the example given is an expected output

Comment: As a side sidenote: regular expressions shouldn't be used to parse natural language as it's not a regular language, regex is **much** slower than string comparison, is **not** pretty nor sturdy, you don't take into account word splitting or the fact the OP would now have two problems.. learning Python and learning Regular Expressions.

Comment: @sudo_O: thanks for the info, i didn't know it was slower. I still think it's a good solution here just because the patterns being searched for are so gosh darn simple so learning enough re for that shouldn't be hard at all. I also don't think word splitting would be an issue here due to the nature of the problem described but I suppose it could be if the code's requirements evolve at all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to write the code to your exact specification as it sounds like homework but this should help:

```
import pprint

words = ['science', 'believe', 'die', 'friend', 'ceiling',
         'receipt', 'seize', 'weird', 'vein', 'foreign']

rule = {}
rule['ie'] = []
rule['ei'] = []
rule['cei'] = []
rule['cie'] = []

for word in words:
    if 'ie' in word:
        if 'cie' in word:
            rule['cie'].append(word)
        else:
            rule['ie'].append(word)
    if 'ei' in word:
        if 'cei' in word:
            rule['cei'].append(word)
        else:
            rule['ei'].append(word)

pprint.pprint(rule)
```

Save it to a file like `i_before_e.py` and run `python i_before_e.py`:

```
{'cei': ['ceiling', 'receipt'],
 'cie': ['science'],
 'ei': ['seize', 'weird', 'vein', 'foreign'],
 'ie': ['believe', 'die', 'friend']}
```

You can easily count the occurrences with:

```
for key in rule.keys():
    print "%s occured %d times." % (key, len(rule[key]))
```

Output:

```
ei occured 4 times.
ie occured 3 times.
cie occured 1 times.
cei occured 2 times.
```

Comment: What don't you understand exactly?

Comment: I pretty much have! If you want code written to exacting specification then higher a developer (I'd be more than happy).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your main problematic is to get unique result per word. Is that what you try to achieve:

```
rule_count = 0
break_count = 0
line = None
while line != '':
    line = input('Line: ')
    rule_found = False
    break_found = False

    for word in line.split():
        if 'cie' in line:
            line = line.replace('cie', '')
            break_found = True
        if 'cei' in line:
            line = line.replace('cei', '')
            rule_found = True
        if 'ie' in line:
            rule_found = True
        if 'ei' in line:
            break_found = True

        if rule_found:
            rule_count += 1
        if break_found:
            break_count += 1

print(rule_found); print(break_count)
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'`

Comment: mixing languages... :)

Comment: `if 'cie' in 'cie': line.replace('cie', '')` should be `if 'cie' in line` and the `replace` isn't necessary to count the occurrences, it's a wrong divergences in the OP original code.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the mistake. By the way I'm not really sure what are the author expectations, and I though one point was to count the 'ie' as a "rule" except when it's 'cie'. This is why I remove 'cie' and 'cei' if found after counting them.

Comment: Since strings are immutable, you need to write `line = line.replace(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's split the logic up into functions, that should help us reason about the code and get it right.  To loop over the line, we can use the `iter` function:

```
def rule_applies(word):
    return 'ei' in word or 'ie' in word

def complies_with_rule(word):
    if 'cie' in word:
        return False
    if word.count('ei') > word.count('cei'):
        return False
    return True

helped_count = 0
broken_count = 0
lines = iter(lambda: input("Line: "), '')
for line in lines:
    for word in line.split():
        if rule_applies(word):
            if complies_with_rule(word):
                helped_count += 1
            else:
                broken_count += 1

print("Number of times the rule helped:", helped_count)
print("Number of times the rule was broken:", broken_count)
```

We can make the code more concise by shortening the `complies_with_rule` function and by using generator expressions and `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

def rule_applies(word):
    return 'ei' in word or 'ie' in word

def complies_with_rule(word):
    return 'cie' not in word and word.count('ei') == word.count('cei')

lines = iter(lambda: input("Line: "), '')
words = (word for line in lines for word in line.split())
words_considered = (word for word in words if rule_applies(word))
did_rule_help_count = Counter(complies_with_rule(word) for word in words_considered)

print("Number of times the rule helped:", did_rule_help_count[True])
print("Number of times the rule was broken:", did_rule_help_count[False])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rule = []
broken = []
tb = 0
tr = 0
line = ' '
while line:
    lines = input('Line: ')
    line = lines.split()


    for word in line:

        if 'ie' in word:
            if 'cie' in word:
                tb += 1
            elif word.count('cie') > 1:
                tb += 1

            elif word.count('ie') > 1:
                tr += 1
            elif 'ie' in word:
                tr += 1

        if 'ei' in word:
            if 'cei' in word:
                tr += 1
            elif word.count('cei') > 1:
                tr += 1

            elif word.count('ei') > 1:
                tb += 1
            elif 'ei' in word:
                tb += 1




print('Number of times the rule helped: {0}'.format(tr))
print('Number of times the rule was broken: {0}'.format(tb))
```

Done.

Comment: Note that most of your script is useless: the test "elif 'ie' in word:" happens inside "if 'ie' in word", so is always true. Moreover, when "if 'cie' in word" is true then "elif word.count('cie')> 1" is necessarily false, so will never happen. Finally you don't give much comments on your solution, whereas there was more detailed solutions.

Comment: Also, words like "obeisancies" are counted as breaking the rule twice, but the requirement say it should only break the rules once.